# IRC - How to assign role to user

Tags: permissions, irc

I wanted to ask how can I assign role to only one person in my IRC channel. I tried command "/msg chanserv access #channel add name role" but it gave that role to everyone in my channel. Then I tried assigning flags manually but with same result.

Comment: Doesn't sounds logical.

Chanserv, when granting user\name an access, it resolves the current "Nickserv Identity" and grant it the desired access.

So unless all your channel users are identified on the same *Identity*, which isn't logical, then it should work well.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already fixed it. Basically I was using 3 accounts and one of them was called random. For some reason user "random" already has SOP permissions. That was the problem :)

Comment: what services software are you using?